# IE8: "ln.innerHTML is either null or not an object"

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, nicedit

I'm using the nicedit.js wysiwyg library and having trouble with the button that inserts a link.

Clicking the button brings up a panel where you enter the url and a title and then click submit: the link should be inserted at your cursor position. But I get the following error in IE8:

> ln.innerHTML is either null or not an object

Error line is:

```
if (this.ln.innerHTML == tmp) {
```

Full Code

```
var nicLinkButton = nicEditorAdvancedButton.extend({    
addPane : function() {
    this.ln = this.ne.selectedInstance.selElm().parentTag('A');
    this.addForm({
        '' : {type : 'title', txt : 'Add/Edit Link'},
        'href' : {type : 'text', txt : 'URL', value : 'http://', style : {width: '150px'}},
        'title' : {type : 'text', txt : 'Title'},
        'target' : {type : 'select', txt : 'Open In', options : {'' : 'Current Window', '_blank' : 'New Window'},style : {width : '100px'}}
    },this.ln);
},

submit : function(e) {        

    var url = this.inputs['href'].value;
    if(url == "http://" || url == "") {
        alert("You must enter a URL to Create a Link");
        return false;
    }
    this.removePane();

    if(!this.ln) {
        var tmp = 'javascript:nicTemp();';
        this.ne.nicCommand("createlink",tmp);
        this.ln = this.findElm('A','href',tmp);
        // set the link text to the title or the url if there is no text selected
        if (this.ln.innerHTML == tmp) {
            this.ln.innerHTML = this.inputs['title'].value || url;
        };
    }
    if(this.ln) {
        var oldTitle = this.ln.title;
        this.ln.setAttributes({
            href : this.inputs['href'].value,
            title : this.inputs['title'].value,
            target : this.inputs['target'].options[this.inputs['target'].selectedIndex].value
        });
        // set the link text to the title or the url if the old text was the old title
        if (this.ln.innerHTML == oldTitle) {
            this.ln.innerHTML = this.inputs['title'].value || this.inputs['href'].value;
        };
    }
}
```

});

Even the example on the nicedit.com homepage doesn't insert the link , though it doesn't show this error either.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer doesn't handle innerHTML the same way as other browsers do, especially if you're talking about table elements. See [here](http://www.jonefox.com/blog/2009/05/21/internet-explorer-and-the-innerhtml-property/) for a discussion.

Depending on your particular situation, there are all sorts of fixes - [this suggestion](http://domscripting.com/blog/display/99) covers most cases. Alternatively, you might have to remove and recreate table elements rather than update their innerHTML, if you want to be IE compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Some simple defensive logic should work:

```
    if (!this.ln.innerHTML || this.ln.innerHTML == tmp) {
        this.ln.innerHTML = this.inputs['title'].value || url;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem raise when no text is selected

my trick for nicEdit, in the situation when no text is selected, is to paste the title given via the Add Link form into the document and select it, then the rest code works as it works when a text is selected.

I used the function pasteHtmlAtCaret described in the following link to paste the title

Insert html at caret in a contenteditable div

```
var selected = getSelected();
if (selected == '')
    pasteHtmlAtCaret(this.inputs['title'].value,true);
if(!this.ln) {
    var tmp = 'javascript:nicTemp();';
    this.ne.nicCommand("createlink",tmp);
    this.ln = this.findElm('A','href',tmp);
    // set the link text to the title or the url if there is no text selected
    if (!this.ln.innerHTML || this.ln.innerHTML == tmp) {
        this.ln.innerHTML = this.inputs['title'].value || url;
    };
}
```

the getSelected is also a simple function as below

```
function getSelected()
{
    if (document.selection)
        return document.selection.createRange().text;
    else
        return window.getSelection();
}
```